# Script to delete large media files older than 2 years with text file of same name & date deleted

Tags: shell

I don't have a preference to PS, Batch or VB

The data is backed up but due to compliance reasons we need markers in place such as text files. The video & photos is consuming 5TB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find command for this.
Example:
find . -type f -size +160k -mtime +7 -delete
Will delete all files that have size > 160k and are "older" than 7 days.

Comment: Thanks Lili, I omitted some critical info so have reposted :-)